# How does the not clause work in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I am trying to find latitudes which fall between two inputs.  My query:

```lisp
(defn- latlngs-within-new-bounds
  [db a w]
  (d/q '[:find ?lat
         :in $ ?a ?w
         :where
         [ ?e :location/lat ?lat]
         [(>= ?lat ?a)]
         (not
          [(>= ?lat ?w)])]
       db a w))
```

My error:

```
3 Unhandled com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: ?lat in this
   context

2 Caused by clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException

1 Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
   Unable to resolve symbol: ?lat in this context

                 Util.java:  221  clojure.lang.Util/runtimeException
```

Any help with understanding what's wrong with my query would be appreciated.  Bonus points if you can also use Datomic rules to factor out the `in-bounds` part of each half.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here:  `(>= :location/lat ?w)`? :location/lat doesn't seem to be comparable to ?w to me

Comment: You are correct.  I have reformatted this to be a more minimal case and a valid query.

Comment: Are you actually executing that query? Since the `a` and `w` parameters in the `:in` line should be `?a` and `?w`.

Comment: Yes, I am.  Yes, there are other structural things which I need to fix.  The error does not pertain to either of those parameters and remains the same when I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me with datomic-free 0.9.5173:

```
(defn- latlngs-within-new-bounds
  [db a w]
  (d/q '[:find ?lat
         :in $ ?a ?w
         :where
         [ ?e :location/lat ?lat]
         [(>= ?lat ?a)]
         (not
           [(>= ?lat ?w)])]
       db a w))

(latlngs-within-new-bounds
  [[1 :location/lat 1]
   [2 :location/lat 2]
   [3 :location/lat 3]
   [4 :location/lat 4]
   [4 :location/lat 5]]
  2 4)
=> #{[2] [3]}
```

Comment: I deleted cider-nrepl from my local maven repo and reran everything and it works now.  Thanks for your help in debugging my tools.